# Sporadic crash while entering emoji in uitextview

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitextview, emoji

I am using UITextView to display a form. I have a restriction to use max 256 characters in UITextView. I also have to display remaining characters count

To implement above requirement I have implemented UITextView Delegate and handled text change event as follows

```
void textViewDidChange()
{
  if (textView.Text.Length >= 256)
    textView.Text = textView.Text.Substring(0, 256);

  var remainingChars = 256 - textView.Text.Trim().Length; **//Crash**
  counterLbl.Text = remainingChars.ToString();
}
```

The code is actually in Xamarin iOS which I have converted in objC for simplification. The problem is when user continuously keeps entering emoji's, at some point textview.text becomes null and application crashes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can enter emoji and get each emoji's length is 2.Could you post more code about how you construct your textView and how to set its delegate. Or please post some error message to help us reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out more about the exception by adding a new breakpoint in Xcode to break on exception, see image, select the breakpoint editor and click the + to add.
[image]

Comment: Hi @nick. thanks for your comment. As I said in my description, textview.text becomes null n that is the exception. Also, I am working in visual studio (Xamarin iOS) so cannot add what you said.

Comment: One of the problems of cross platform tools. I am currently using Cordova and sometimes the Safari Web Inspector works, sometimes it doesn't.